# How can i develop an OpenGL ES application with Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl-es

I've been trying to make an application using Qt + OpenGL ES, so that it would run on devices but i can't seem to find any code on it, and the only few i could find wouldn't build. And when i searched for why it wasn't building people would say that i had to wait for a new version of Qt or something like that.

Anyone has ever done it? If so, there is a tutorial out there or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples for [OpenGL ES 1.0](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-opengl-hellogl-example.html) and OpenGL ES 2.0 are in examples/opengl/ of your Qt installation.

If you are targeting to Symbian, you need to wait Qt 4.7 and it's "experimental" OpenGL ES support for Symbian. With Maemo (N900), OpenGL ES 2.0 has been working since Qt 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

Just as regular openGL - you just can't use a few features like pixel buffers

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windowsce-opengl.html

Answer (score 0):

[Qt OpenGL](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter14.html) Nehe tutorials converted to the Qt environment

I haven't tried it yet, so hopefully will help.